# No output for a Postgres query executed in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, postgresql

I am running a Postgres query that is returning no output when run in Visual Studio. In PGAdmin, the correct output is returned
Other, simpler queries run fine, but this one does not. The structure of this one is

```
drop table if exists temp_one;
drop table  if exists temp_two;

create temp table temp_one as
select (some query);

create temp table temp_two as
select (some other query);

select *
from temp_one
join temp_two on temp_one.foo = temp_two.foo
```

Running the whole thing gives no result, but running just the final select does return the correct result, assuming temp_one and temp_two have been properly created this session.

Would anyone know why Visual Studio does not produce an output?
Thanks

Comment: Is Visual Studio connecting to the database as the same user (or as a user with the same permissions) as you do with pgAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Many such tools (now including pg_admin) will not return results for more than one query run at the same time as a script.  Currently pgAdmin will not do this if these are run as a transaction either.  Your best bet is to run the queries using a tool like psql where you have a lot more control over output.  The psql interface is actually remarkably powerful and gives you many things that your IDE's won't including the ability to cycle through results of multiple queries like this.